# Shell - New line seperator in python script output

Tags: python, shell

How do I specify a new line in python output? Because the code below is not working.

Already tried 'os.linesep'.

```
LOGS=$(echo "$RESPONSE" | python -c "
import sys, json, os;
res=json.load(sys.stdin);
result=''
for x in range(len(res['hits']['hits'])):
    result += res['hits']['hits'][x]['_source']['message'] + '\n'

print result
")
    
echo -e $LOGS
```

Comment: Try echo -e "$LOGS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to echo the variable $LOG in quotes to expand any carriage returns. The last line should therefore be:

```
echo -e "$LOGS"
```